# facebook api login issue, token does not existe

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using currently Facebook API php sdk login with a callback URL, the code in my local machine is working perfectly but when i put it on server and change the links to the new domain it doesn't work anymore, the the callback URL doesn't get any token from the app any help pls
this is my code

```
<?php 
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk-5/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'appid',
  'app_secret' => 'appsecret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7',
]);

session_start();
//session_destroy(); exit;

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'publish_actions']; // optional


# login-callback.php

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if(isset($_GET['fb_email'])) {

    echo '<a>Facebook!</a>';

    if(!empty($_GET['fb_email']) and filter_var($_GET['fb_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {



        include_once 'function file';
        $name=$_SESSION['fb_user_info']['name'];
        $email=$_GET['fb_email'];
        $id_network=$_SESSION['fb_user_info']['id'];
        $network="facebook";
        $res=functionname($parameters);
        if($res==0){
          //echo "<script>alert('ajouter avec succes');</script>";
          header("location:etape-1.php");
        }
        else{
          //echo "<script>alert('id existe deja ');</script>";
          header("location:etape-1.php");
        }
    }

}

else if (isset($accessToken)) {

    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;


    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $user = $response->getGraphUser();
    $_SESSION['fb_user_info']=$user;


    echo '<a>Facebook!</a>';


    if($user['email']=="" or $user['email']=="undefined" or is_null($user['email'])) {
        header('location:?fb_email=notfound');
    }
    else {
        include_once 'function file';
        $name=$user['name'];
        $email=$user['email'];
        $id_network=$user['id'];
        $network="facebook";
        $res=functionname($parameters);
        if($res==0){
          //echo "<script>alert('ajouter avec succes');</script>";
          header("location:etape-1.php");
        }
        else{
          //echo "<script>alert('id existe deja ');</script>";
          header("location:etape-1.php");
        }
    }

}
else {

    /*$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(
        array('scope'         => 'publish_actions,email')
    );*/
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://callbacklink',
                    array(
                'scope'         => 'email,publish_actions'
            )
        );
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '" id="loginFacebook">Facebook!</a>';
}
```

?>

this is the link if u wanna test pls http://jeu.reseaubmwrecrute.com/jeu.php use facebook connection

Comment: Your callback URL answers with a 500 status code after I return from the FB login dialog. Most likely that means you did not properly catch an exception thrown by the SDK. Go check your error log.

Comment: yes it was an internal server error has nothing to do with the code thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change php.ini to allow_url_fopen=on and you should be able to access from the site.